# Ampps rejects my Mac user password when I open it

Tags: passwords, 64-bit, macos-catalina, ampps

I installed AMPPS using the "website" and "brew cask" but in both times when I enter the mac user password it gives "the password you entered is incorrect"

I thought i typed the password wrong or something
so I typed it in a text file and copied it the passowrd field and to check if I typed the password wrong again pasted for `sudo` as well

does anyone have the same problem or know a solution

https://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=16184

**softaculous communication by codecreator**

[image]

Comment: form the no comment I can deduce that no one is having the same problem progress never the less

Comment: I am having the exact same problem on Catalina as I type this

Comment: I tried following what other users did on the official forum, but no success so far https://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?as=ksrs3kletqce9mgkngx8g2b8xyirlhtr&tid=15991&title=AMPPS64_is_unusable_on_Catalina

Comment: @chriscatfr  if still having the same problem can you please upvote the question to first get attention and secondly to make a bounty. thank u

Comment: @Athman if still having the same problem can you please upvote the question to first get attention and secondly to make a bounty. thank u

Answer (score 3):

### The new AMPPS has some strange security configuration with the login not allowing special characters.

I changed the password as per gcrum suggestion then logged in AMPPS saving the password. Then I was able to return my original password with AMPPS still working.

---

Thanks to gcrum for figuring it out.

> I think I figured this problem out. It wants to use your Mac login password AND it can't have any special characters in it. If you change your password to alpha numeric only it does work. Not very secure and very stupid, but was able to get past the password prompt.

## Edit (7 Apr):

Although the password trick worked to run the app, adding domains did not work and after restarting the mac only the MySQL server started.

Comment: Worked for me after removing special characters from my password. Apache, php and mysql started running... thanks

Comment: is there a way to force it to accept my actual password (containing special characters)?

Comment: until know it is not working. for now am using `https://lando.dev` and plugin for vscode `https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jixabon.lando-ui` it's docker but easier to work with @mina

Answer (score 1):

I'm having same symptom when starting Ampps which has just been downloaded.
In my case, the password is normal (no special characters), it was caused by another issue.

I tried this and solved my issue: **right click** Ampps.app, click "Open" to start Ampps. Then now enter the same password. Check "Remember" so next time it can start Ampps normally without asking for password again.

Comment: Your answer is misleading to say the problem is not caused by special characters. I personally solved the issue by removing special characters, also many other users confirm to have solved it this way. Additionally I had tried solving by clicking that remember password button to no avail.

Comment: you are right, my answer might make misleading. What I said is the problem in my case only, I just wanted to add another possible issue to check.
[Edited my answer]

Comment: Now it makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days and in a forum (I leave the link below) I found a solution that at least worked for me.

https://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?as=ksrs3kletqce9mgkngx8g2b8xyirlhtr&tid=15991&title=AMPPS64_is_unusable_on_Catalina

Do this in Terminal with the DMG you downloaded from the AMPPS site

`xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine /Applications/AMPPS/`

Then install (drag to Applications) as it is done regularly and it should work without problems and not have that error with the password.

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the ";" character in the password to create problem. hopefully it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with AMPPS when working on max os...

The issue was file permission to Mac directories...
it requires full file control...
please follow these steps.

go to:
apple icon top left of your screen.
click it the click system preferences...
then click Security & privacy
click the privacy tab...

click full disk access from the left menu you will need to scroll down
then click the padlock to the unlock position and then add AMPPS by pressing the plus icon and navigating to AMPPS install directory and locating the AMPPS.app

once you have added it my prompt you to restart AMPPS... allow the restart to happen and the issue should be resolved in full please message me if you have issues following these steps and I will add screen shots step by step.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

In my case i go to /Applications/AMPPS/ , right click on Ampps.app -> Show Package Contents - > Contents -> MacOS , right click on Ampps file and Open

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. It is asking your Mac password not softaculous password. It worked when i entered my Mac pass.